# How to find the area of a triangle given some ratios of its segments?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm studying for a university entrance exam in Japan and sometimes in the trigonometry section in the exam there are questions like this related to the ratios of a triangle's sides.

For example

In a triangle $ABC$, points $D$ and $E$ are located at segment $AB$ and $AC$ respectively. Also $AD:AE = 3:5$, and segment $DE$ and $BC$ intersect at point $F$.

When $AD:BD = 2:3$, $AE:CE = 2:1$, the area of triangle $ADE$ is $S$ and the area of the quadrilateral $BCED$ is $T$

Then: $S:T$ = ?

I tried multiple times but could not solve it, is probably something fairly simple but i do not know what to do, can someone help?

I will upload the original question in japanese

[image]

Comment: If $D$ is on $\overline{AB}$ and $E$ is on $\overline{AC}$ then $\overline{BC}$ and $\overline{DE}$ can only intersect if $D$ or $E$ are outside $\triangle ABC$. Correct?

Comment: $D$ and $E$ can belong to △ABC and intersect at $F$ but then $F$ is outside the triangle. If this doesn't makes sense then i messed something in the translation.

Comment: So $F$ is only mentioned to ensure $\overline{BC} \nparallel \overline{DE}$?

Comment: At the first question yes, at the second question the ratio of BF:CF is asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect B to E. We have:

$\frac{AE}{CE}=\frac21 \Rightarrow A_{AEB}=2A_{BEC}$

Also:

$ \frac{AD}{BD}=\frac 23 \Rightarrow A_{AEB}=A_{AED}+A_{EDB}=\frac 52 A_{AED} $

$A_{ABC}=A_{AED}+A_{BEC}$

$\Rightarrow A_{ABC}=A_{AED}+\frac 54 A_{AED}=\frac 94 A_{AED}$

which gives:

$\frac{A_{AED}}{A_{ABC}}=\frac 49$

$A_{EDBC}=A_{ABC}-A_{AED}$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Science boy, You'r welcome.